# For loop that displays values from -5 through 5 and then back to -5 in increments of 1

Tags: c

I understand this code, but one thing is not clear to me.
What means`(;)` in this line  `for(;c>=-5;c--)`?

```
for(c=-5;c<5;c++)
    printf("%d ",c);
for(;c>=-5;c--)
    printf("%d ",c);
putchar('\n');
return(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

A `for` loop has three parts.

The first is an initialization that runs once when the loop is first entered.  The second is the comparison, which is checked just before entering the loop body, and the third is the loop incrementer, which runs when the loop jumps back to the top.

Any of these three parts may be omitted.  In this case, the initialization part is missing, which means nothing is done for this step.

Answer (score -1):

the `for`-loop can be written as a three-part `while`-loop

```
for(part1; part2; part3) {
  statement
}

part1;
while (part2) {
  statement;
  part3;
}
```

in your case, the `part1` is empty, so the counter will not be initialised; and it therefore will be keept the value it had, when left the first loop;

Comment: This is not the same.